# How pointers in C/C++ actually store addresses?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-address

If an `int` is stored in memory in 4 bytes each if which having a unique address, which address of these four addresses does a pointer to that `int` store?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, read the description of the tags that you applied. Further reading concerning your question: "endianess".

Comment: If you want a theoretical approach, read about [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics); if you want a pragmatical approach, study the [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) of your C or your C++ compiler (e.g. [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)...), and ask your compiler to show assembler code: with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O`

Comment: The address is unsigned value - 32 or 64 bit, depends on CPU. It can be 16-bit in some cases. The pointer is variable located somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 12):

A pointer to `int` (a `int*`) stores the address of the first byte of the integer. The size of `int` is known to the compiler, so it just needs to know where it starts.
How the bytes of the `int` are interpreted depends on the endianness of your machine, but that doesn't change the fact that the pointer just stores the starting address (the endianness is also known to the compiler).

Comment: Better mention the endianness and how it may change the first byte interpretation.

Comment: @aep first byte is the first byte regardless the endianess.

Comment: @P__J__ Technically true. I was commenting it since, mentioning it may enhance the answer. Endianness will decide how the int is interpreted not the first byte.

Comment: @eap from the C point of view unless you pun the types endianess does not matter. if `p` is a pointer referencing the `int` the `*p` will always have the correct value. IMO endianess are not relevant to the OP  question

Answer (score 2):

Those 4 `int` bytes are not stored in the random locations - they are consecutive. So it is enough to store the reference (address) of first byte of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the architecture.  On a big-endian architecture (M68K, IBM z series), it’s usually the address of the most significant byte.  On a little-endian architecture (x86), it’s usually the address of the least-significant byte:

```
 A   A+1 A+2 A+3    big-endian
+–––+–––+–––+–––+
|msb|   |   |lsb|
+–––+–––+–––+–––+
 A+3 A+2 A+1 A      little-endian
```

There may be other oddball addressing schemes I’m leaving out.

But basically it’s whatever the underlying architecture considers the “first” byte of the word.

Comment: Your illustration is a bit confusing.  The address is that of the byte with the lowest address, regardless of the current endianness in the target system.

Comment: *Depends on the architecture* no, I'm afraid it does not.

Comment: It depends, @chqrlie, on whether you're talking about addresses in the C abstract-machine-model sense or in the hardware sense.  These are not required to coincide.  In fact, that they might not coincide is the reason for a great deal of the obtuseness of the standard's definitions of pointer and pointer-operation semantics.  Moreover, it depends also on how one means the "first" byte of an integer -- in one of at least two possible place-value senses, or in the sense of some addressing model or other.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: not really as incrementing a pointer to `int` makes it point to the next `int` in an array of `int`. On a hypothetical CPU where an `int *` contains the address of the *last* byte (ie: the one with the greatest address), casting this pointer as an `(unsigned char*)` would have to change its value to produce an `unsigned char *` pointing to the byte with the lowest address.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, confused objects with bytes. My bad. Already deleted my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @chqrlie: But whichever byte is the lowest-addressed byte *is* dependent on architecture.  If you map that `int` onto a sequence of `unsigned char`, you’ll get a different ordering for BE than for LE.  Again, on some architectures, the lowest-addressed byte is the most significant, while on others it’s the least significant.

Comment: @JohnBode: I agree with your comment, but it is irrelevant for the question: *which address of these four addresses does a pointer to that `int` store?* In practice this address is the lowest address, regardless of endianness... Although in theory the representation of pointers is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

> If an `int` is stored in memory in 4 bytes which each has a unique address, which address of these four addresses does a Pointer to that `int` store?

A pointer to `int` *usually* stores the address value of the first byte (which is stored at the lowest memory address) of the `int` object.

Hence the size of the `int` is known and constant at a specific implementation/ architecture and an `int` object is always stored in consecutive bytes (there are no bytes between two of them), it is clear that the following ((if `sizeof(int) == 4`) three) bytes belong to the same `int` object.

How the bytes of the `int` object are interpreted is dependent upon Endianness*.

The first byte is usually automatically aligned on a multiple of the data word size dependent upon a specific architecture, so that the CPU can work most efficiently.

In a 32-bit architecture for example, when the data word size is 4, the first byte lies on a 4-byte boundary - an address location with a multiple of 4.

`sizeof(int)` is not always `4` (although common) by the way.

---

<sup>*Endianness can influence if the interpretation of the object starts at the *most* (the first) or *least* (the last) *significant byte*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard does not specify how addresses are represented inside pointers. Yet on most current architectures, a pointer to an `int` stores its address as the offset in the process' memory space of the first byte of memory used to store it, more precisely the byte with the lowest address.

Note however these remarks:

- the `int` may have more or fewer than 32 bits. The only constraint is it must have at least 15 value bits and a sign bit.
- bytes may have more than 8 bits. Most current architectures use 8-bit bytes but early Unix systems had 9-bit bytes, and some DSP systems have 16-, 24- or even 32-bit bytes.
- when an `int` is stored using multiple bytes, it is unspecified how its bits are split among these bytes. Many systems use little-endian representation where the least-significant bits are in the first byte, other systems use big-endian representation where the most significant bits and the sign bit are in the first byte. Other representations are possible but only in theory.
- many systems require that the address of the `int` be aligned on a multiple of their size.
- how pointers are stored in memory is also system specific and unspecified. Addresses do not necessarily represent offsets in memory, real of virtual. For example 64-bit pointers on x86 CPUs have a number of bits that can be ignored or that may contain a cryptographic signature verified on the fly by the CPU. Adding one to the stored value of a pointer does not necessarily produce a valid pointer.